# Displaying PNG images from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm trying to display an image from a MySQL database and my code works fine if the image is a JPG, but if I modify the content-type to display a PNG, it doesn't work...
How do I make it work for PNG??

```
<?php

    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php"); 

    header('Content-type: image/JPG');
    $username = "xxxxx";
    $password = "*****";
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "database";
    @mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error());
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $row['image'];
    }
?>
```

Also, is it possible to display the image along with its name and description? 
Thanks!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: To display PNG images, put PNG images in your database.  To display JPG images, put JPG images in your database.

Comment: I tried with JPG and PNG images in my dadtabase, but the code only displays the JPG's, when I try to display PNG's I just get that little broken image.

Comment: You may want to look at your content type...

Comment: Yes, when I wanna display JPG I write: header('Content-type: image/JPG'); and it works
and when I wanna display PNG: header('Content-type: image/PNG'); = broken image.

Comment: I would recommend saving your images outside of your database. Just include the link to the location in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind not supporting older browsers, you can use data urls to display your images and a description http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme.

```
<figure>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['image']); ?>" alt="Your alternative text" />
  <figcaption>Some more description</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Saving images in a database is not very useful in almost all cases. You should be carefull with upper and lower letters in the mimetype, see http://de.selfhtml.org/diverses/mimetypen.htm (it's german, but you will be able to read the list). And as a last advice - look at the mysqli_* functions http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.

// Edit: Just an idea, but if you have multiple images in the database your image might be broken, because you just put them all into one image. This will not work! With your code, you can only display one image at once.

Comment: I'm testing this with just one image in my database...not with the "real" database. Thanks for the answer.